# set data into recyclerview using gson in android

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to set recyclerview data from this type of `json` response but data is not setting into recylerview

Response:

```
   {
    "vehicles": [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "vehicle_number": "gj03fn3235",
        "driver_id": 4,
        "vehicle_type": "3",

        "admindata": {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "chirag.pwt2@gmail.com"

        },
        "userdata": {
            "id": 4,
            "email": "keval.pwt@gmail.com"

        }
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "vehicle_number": "gj03fn3236",
        "driver_id": 4,
        "vehicle_type": "4",

        "admindata": {
            "id": 7,
            "email": "keval.pwt@gmail.com"

        },
        "userdata": {
            "id": 4,
            "email": "keval.pwt@gmail.com"

          }
      }
  ]
}
```

I have created a pojo class of response But my data is not setting into recylerview api call successfully but response print in `logcat` i tried to set vehicle_number and email in recylerview

Here is my java code:

```
   @Override
        public void onSuccess(int 
statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject 
response) {
            super.onSuccess(statusCode, 
     headers, response);

            try {
                Gson gson = new 
 GsonBuilder().create();

                List<VehicleList> list = 

   gson.fromJson(response.getJSONArray
   ("vehicles").toString(), new 
   TypeToken<List<VehicleList>>() {
                }.getType());

   Log.e("listsize",""+list.size());

                if (list.size() == 0) {

    txt_error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    VehiclesDriverAdpter 
  acceptedRequestAdapter = new 
  VehiclesDriverAdpter(list);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter
  (acceptedRequestAdapter);
  acceptedRequestAdapter.
  notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }


        }
```

My Adapter class:

```
 public class VehiclesDriverAdpter extends 
  RecyclerView.Adapter<VehiclesDriverAdpter.Holder> {
 List<VehicleList> list;
 List<Vehicle> list1;
 FragmentActivity activity;

 public VehiclesDriverAdpter(List<VehicleList> list) {
    this.list = list;
 }



 @Override
 public Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new 


 Holder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
 .inflate(R.layout.adapter_vehicle, parent, false));
}

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(final Holder holder, int position) {
    final Vehicle pojo1 = list1.get(position);

    Log.e("VehicleNumber",""+pojo1.getVehicleNumber());


    holder.txt_vehicle_number.setText(pojo1.getVehicleNumber());
    holder.txt_vehicle_driver_name.setText(pojo1.getUserdata().getEmail());
    holder.drivername.setText(pojo.getDriver_name());




    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("data", pojo1);
            VehiclesInfoFragment detailFragment = new 
    VehiclesInfoFragment();
            detailFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            ((HomeActivity) holder.itemView.getContext()).
    changeFragment(detailFragment, "Passenger Information");
        }
    });
    BookFont(holder, holder.txt_vehilce_type);
    BookFont(holder, holder.txt_vehicle_driver_name);
    BookFont(holder, holder.txt_vehicle_driver_mobile_no);

    MediumFont(holder, holder.txt_vehicle_number);



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {



    TextView txt_vehicle_number, txt_vehilce_type, txt_vehicle_driver_name, 
    txt_vehicle_driver_mobile_no;
    CircleImageView img_driver;

    public Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        txt_vehicle_number = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vehicle_number);
        txt_vehilce_type = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vehilce_type);
         txt_vehicle_driver_name = (TextView) 
   itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vehicle_driver_name);
        txt_vehicle_driver_mobile_no = (TextView) 
    itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_vehicle_driver_mobile_no);

    }
}

   public void BookFont(Holder holder, TextView view1) {
    Typeface font1 = 
   Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), 
"font/AvenirLTStd_Book.otf");
    view1.setTypeface(font1);
}

   public void MediumFont(Holder holder, TextView view) {
    Typeface font = 
    Typeface.createFromAsset(holder.itemView.getContext().getAssets(), 
   "font/AvenirLTStd_Medium.otf");
    view.setTypeface(font);
}
```

}

Comment: Are u getting a blank layout?

Comment: yes, i get blank layout

Comment: @DharmiPatel please post your recycle activity code

Comment: if you are using retrofit using rxjava, than execute last notify code in UI thread, may be in runonuithread

Comment: i edit my code @RahulChokshi

Comment: @DharmiPatel please check your `JSON` is not valid response. check in https://jsonformatter.org/json-editor

Comment: @DharmiPatel as requested by others, can you please share the entire class responsible for making API call and displaying the list. Also share the Pojo class/es as there might be a spelling mistake (best to have multiple set of eyes looking at it then one)

Comment: @Nero first check provided response is not valid json response.

Comment: First check _list.size()_

Comment: list size is 1@Piyush

Comment: Show your `VehiclesDriverAdpter` class. Don't need to refresh adapter.

Comment: @DharmiPatel did you check run window anything wrong over there

Comment: i add my VehiclesDriverAdpter  class @Piyush

Comment: This is wrong `Vehicle pojo1 = list1.get(position)`. Your actual list is _list.size()_ So you need to change it by `Vehicle pojo1 = list.get(position)`

Comment: if i update Vehicle pojo1 = list.get(position) it give error

Comment: Its your class cast exception.

Comment: @DharmiPatel, Is your issue solved?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
                 setRecyclerData();
         }
});

   private void setRecyclerData(){
        VehiclesDriverAdpter acceptedRequestAdapter = new VehiclesDriverAdpter(list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(acceptedRequestAdapter);
        acceptedRequestAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to add layout manager on your recyclerView add it in code like this

```
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    VehiclesDriverAdpter acceptedRequestAdapter = new  VehiclesDriverAdpter(list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter  (acceptedRequestAdapter);
```

Comment: It would've been a better approach to request the code within the MainActivity before making assumptions on what has and hasn't been implemented.

Comment: Yes you are right but in the provided code by Dharmi , It has only the layout manager issue with recyclerView , as he is already updating view after success response on main thread, I am not sure but i am assuming by his code

Comment: Can you please post complete code of your activity?

Comment: are you getting List<VehicleList> list is not empty ?, because in your json there are some fields missing from first json object

Answer (score 0):

You put data to  `List<VehicleList> list` list, but take it from `List<Vehicle> list1`;
You can try(but only if you always have one item in VehicleList) something like this

```
public VehiclesDriverAdpter(List<VehicleList> list) {
  if(!list.isEmpty()){
   this.list1 = list.get(0);
  }
 }
```